# I think the author's proof of Theorem 4-4(1) is not correct. ("Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

[image]

I think the author's proof of Theorem 4-4(1) is not correct.

Am I right?

The author wrote as follows in the proof of Theorem 4-4(1):

> $$\sum_{\sigma\in G\cdot\sigma_0} \text{sgn }\sigma\cdot S(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(k)})\cdot T(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(k+l)}) =\left[\text{sgn }\sigma_0\cdot\sum_{\sigma'\in G}\text{sgn }\sigma'\cdot S(w_{\sigma'(1)},\dots,w_{\sigma'(k)})\right]\cdot T(w_{k+1},\dots,w_{k+l})
> =0.$$

But I think the following is correct:

> $$\sum_{\sigma\in \sigma_0\cdot G} \text{sgn }\sigma\cdot S(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(k)})\cdot T(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(k+l)})
> \\=\sum_{\sigma'\in G} \text{sgn }(\sigma_0\cdot\sigma')\cdot S(v_{\sigma_0\cdot\sigma'(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma_0\cdot\sigma'(k)})\cdot T(v_{\sigma_0\cdot\sigma'(k+1)},\dots,v_{\sigma_0\cdot\sigma'(k+l)})
> \\=\text{sgn }\sigma_0\cdot\sum_{\sigma'\in G} \text{sgn }\sigma'\cdot S(w_{\sigma'(1)},\dots,w_{\sigma'(k)})\cdot T(w_{\sigma'(k+1)},\dots,w_{\sigma'(k+l)})
> \\=\text{sgn }\sigma_0\cdot\sum_{\sigma'\in G} \text{sgn }\sigma'\cdot S(w_{\sigma'(1)},\dots,w_{\sigma'(k)})\cdot T(w_{k+1},\dots,w_{k+l})
> \\=\left[\text{sgn }\sigma_0\cdot\sum_{\sigma'\in G}\text{sgn }\sigma'\cdot S(w_{\sigma'(1)},\dots,w_{\sigma'(k)})\right]\cdot T(w_{k+1},\dots,w_{k+l})
> =0.$$

The author defined $w_1,\dots,w_{k+l}$ as follows:
$v_{\sigma_0(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma_0(k+l)}=w_1,\dots,w_{k+l}$.
So, $v_{\sigma_0\cdot\sigma'(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma_0\cdot\sigma'(k+l)}=w_{\sigma'(1)},\dots,w_{\sigma'(k+l)}$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Spivak's formula is correct, yours is not. Please re-read the definition of the $w_i$s.

Comment: @AnneBauval I edited my question.

Comment: I apologize, now I think *you* are correct. I had a glance at the proof of the previous theorem (4.3), where the notation $\sigma\cdot\tau$ clearly denotes $\sigma\circ\tau$, not $\tau\circ\sigma$ as one could believe from this proof of theorem 4.4.

Comment: Which Edition of Spivak is this? I think my version just considers the complete product $S\otimes T$

Comment: @ContraKinta I added pictures of my book which is not corrected.

Comment: @ContraKinta 27th printing, January 1998.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I recognized this but didn't remember Spivak being so unclear. So I looked it up and it turns out this is basically the same proof Spivak gives in "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry" but it seems your version is from the 1960s and this is the corrected updated 1999 version:

[image]

Comment: ContraKinta, Thank you very much for your answer.